# Changing Axis Labels on Excel Chart created in C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

So I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but can't seem to get anywhere. I'm creating an Excel spreadsheet using C#. My spreadsheet contains a chart. I'm able to do everything with the chart EXCEPT change the X-Axis labels. I've tried just about everything that i can find but nothing works.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlChart = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart.Add(1420, 660, 320, 180);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Title Text";
chartPage.HasLegend = false;

var yAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
yAxis.HasTitle = true;
yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Y-Axis Title text";
yAxis.MaximumScale = 20;
yAxis.AxisTitle.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpward;

Excel.Range Data_Range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A10", "C10");//Data to be plotted in chart
Excel.Range XVal_Range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1");//Catagory Names I want on X-Axis as range
var x_labels = new List<string>() { "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" }; //Catagory Names I want on X-Axis as text array

Excel.SeriesCollection oSeriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(misValue);
Excel.Series Data = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
Data.Values = Data_Range;
Data.Name = "Plot Data";

Excel.Axis valueAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
/*
Methods I've tried with no luck:
1) Data.XValues = XVal_Range;
2) Data.XValues = x_labels.ToArray();
3) valueAxis.CategoryNames = x_labels.ToArray();
4) valueAxis.CategoryNames = XVal_Range;
*/
```

each time it just displays with the default number values... I'm at a loss

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so i figured out the problem... You can't change the X-Axis on a Scatter type graph. I changed the type of graph to `Excel.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;` and it worked fine.

Here's the entire snippet:

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlChart = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart.Add(1420, 660, 320, 180);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Title Text";
chartPage.HasLegend = false;

var yAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
yAxis.HasTitle = true;
yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Y-Axis Title text";
yAxis.MaximumScale = 20;
yAxis.AxisTitle.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpward;

Excel.Range Data_Range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A10", "C10");//Data to be plotted in chart
Excel.Range XVal_Range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1");//Catagory Names I want on X-Axis as range

Excel.SeriesCollection oSeriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(misValue);
Excel.Series Data = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
Data.Values = Data_Range;
Data.Name = "Plot Data";

Excel.Axis xAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
xAxis.CategoryNames = XVal_Range;
```

Comment: It worked for me. can you please tell me how can I change the value of **Horizontal Axis**??
Because right now it is simply 1,2,3,4,5.... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change both X and Y Axis Title

```
    var yAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
    yAxis.HasTitle = true;
    yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Y Label";

    var xAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
    xAxis.HasTitle = true;
    xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "X Label";
```